# Sort dataframe include empty field

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below:

```
data = {'Test': [' ', ' ', 'K', ],
        'Name': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
        'value': ['D1', 'A1', ' ', 'C1'],
        'time': [227, 227, 227, 230]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
  Test  Name value  time
0        A    D1    227
1        B    A1    227
2   K    B          227
3        B    C1    230
```

And I want to make the df to sort as:

```
  Test  Name value  time
0        A    D1    227
1   K    B          227
2        B    A1    227
3        B    C1    230
```

I've tried using `sort_values`, but still can't figure it out. Or should I add more condition for the empty field ' '(or NA) in sort?

Comment: a string starting with a whitespace will be sorted before other lettres. so `df.sort_values(['Name','value'])` seems to work with this data? maybe explicit a bit more what sorting you want!

Comment: @Ben.T Thanks for the reminder, I didn't notice that whitespace will be sorted before other lettres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better not use empty strings/spaces to denote empty cells. Use NAs/NaNs that are directly handled by [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
out = (df.replace(' ', pd.NA)
         .sort_values(by=['Name', 'time', 'Test'])
       )
```

Which is equivalents to:

```
out = (df.replace(' ', pd.NA)
         .sort_values(by=['Name', 'time', 'Test'], na_position='last')
       )
```

Output:

```
   Test Name value  time
0  <NA>    A    D1   227
2     K    B  <NA>   227
1  <NA>    B    A1   227
3  <NA>    B    C1   230
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Test': [' ', ' ', 'K', ' '],
        'Name': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
        'value': ['D1', 'A1', ' ', 'C1'],
        'time': [227, 227, 227, 230]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["Test"] = df["Test"].replace(" ", "Zzzzz") #Replace whitespaces with zs which will sort them last
df = df.sort_values(by=["Name","time","Test"])
df["Test"] = df["Test"].replace("Zzzzz", " ") 

#   Test  Name value  time
# 0        A    D1    227
# 1   K    B          227
# 2        B    A1    227
# 3        B    C1    230
```

Comment: Thanks, I found my mistake, just replace the whitespace to other letter or pd.NA. And it can be sorted as i want